# How to display a BufferedImage in JApplet

Tags: java, paint, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

No images are displayed on the japplet.

```
  public void setCharacter(String type)
 {
  try
  {
   character = ImageIO.read(new File(type));
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

That's how I retrieve the file.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

  g2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

  switch (manipulateCase)
  {
   case 0:
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, xBound, yBound)); // painting the background.
    break;

   case 1:
    normandy.delete(g2); // delete previous position
    ImageIcon stuff = new ImageIcon("spaceship.jpg");
    stuff.paintIcon(this, g2, 0, 0);
    //g2.drawImage(normandy.getImage(), normandy.getBounds().x, normandy.getBounds().y, null); // draw new position
    break;

   /*case 2:
    for (int i = 0; i < aLevel.getInvaders().length; i++) {
     g2.fill(aLevel.getInvaders()[i].getCharacter());
    }
    break;

   case 3:
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    if (bullets.getBullets().size() > 0)
     for (int i = 0; i < bullets.getBullets().size(); i++) {
      g2.fill(bullets.getBullets().get(i).getBullet());
      System.out.println("BULLETS: "
        + bullets.getBullets().size());
     }
    break;

   case 4:
    break; */
  }

 }
```

The above code is in the applet.

What am i doing wrong? Why am I getting the error. "Cannot read input file!"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
blargman

Comment: I didn't know people still used applets?

Comment: @VoodooChild - Is that a statement or a question?  Taking it as a question.  Of course they do!  In fact, with the slew of extra functionality introduced in the new generation plug-in (including draggable applets, and access to JNLP services) there is a resurgence of interest in embedded applets.

Comment: In addition to the advice of maaartinus, I would recommend 1) Never load images in the paint()/paintComponent() method - instead load them in init() and cache them as class level attributes. 2) Never override paint() in a top level Swing container.  Instead do it in a JComponent and override paintComponent().  This both saves confusion and allows the customized component to be more versatile about where it is put and what other GUI controls might be added as well.

Answer (score 1):

Where does the file reside? An applet running in a browser can't read a file on your computer, it can only access it via a URL. It could access a file on the remote computer, but is normally (for a good reason) not allowed to. So replace `new ImageIcon(String filename)` by `new ImageIcon(URL location)`.

Comment: I don't have a URL. My teacher wants us to make an applet that would run on his site. Is there a way of allowing it access the files in the package?

Comment: You always have an URL. Use `getClass().getResource("spaceship.jpg")` in case the image resides in the same directory as the class. Add a leading slash in case it resides in a directory listen on the CLASSPATH. Use a pathname in case it resides elsewhere. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String) This way it will work no matter how the applet gets invoked.

Comment: can i use a BufferedImage instead of an icon?

Comment: There's a constructor ImageIcon(Image image), so you can convert any Image into an Icon. So yes.

Comment: sorry to bother you again but i'm still having trouble finding the file. This is where it is on my computer. "/Users/Me/AP Computer Science Part A/workspace/Space Invaders Revamp/spaceship.jpg". What should i type in to get the URL of the file? thanx

Comment: It depends on where your classes lie. You can always use something like "file://Users/Me/AP Computer Science Part A/workspace/Space Invaders Revamp/spaceship.jpg", but this is no good idea. Move the image to where it "belongs". As the simplest solution move it to the same directory as your java-file reading it. Do a refresh in your IDE, so it sees it.

Answer (score -1):

Custom painting should not be done by overriding the paint() method.

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) for more details on writing an applet. There is also a section on "Loading Images into Applets".

I also agree to learn how to do painting is is easier to just practice with a simple application that uses a JFrame. You can read the section from the Swing tutorial on "Custom Painting" for more examples. The tutorial is full of great information and examples.

Comment: hmmm... it seems interesting. But some of the concepts covered are a bit advanced for me. I don't understand half the concepts they talk about.

Comment: Yes, it's not easy, but you'll need it, sooner or later. As for the overriding of `paint`, override `paintComponent` instead.

Comment: The question states that the object is a `JApplet`. `JApplet` does not have `paintComponent` (because it extends `Applet` not `JPanel`.)  If there's a design smell in the question it's the fact that he is trying to implement the appearance my modifying the applet instead of adding a custom component to it.

Comment: @finnw, I don't know why I got the down vote, I never suggested to override paintComponent() of the JApplet. I suggested the poster should read the tutorial on "Custom Painting" which shows the proper way to do custom painting.